# How do switches work in ltspice?

Tags: power-electronics, ltspice, buck

I Have set up my switch according to the rules specified, using the dot command to determine the behavior of the switch but I still get the error.

"Can't find definition of model 'S1'"

I have attached my circuit and the results, which are wrong the output should be five volts as per my calculations

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Well, you defined a model called MYSW, then attempted to instantiate a model called S1, so of course it doesn't work.

You seem to have put MYSW as the name of the switch, and S1 as the model it should use, instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

As it was mentioned before, MYSW should be in the field "Value" and S1 in the "InstName".

I will also suggest changing the Pulse generator (V2), as with the setup of the photo, the output will be a constant value. Maybe something like this:

```
PULSE(0 1 0 1u 1u 25u 50u)
```

Regarding the questions, I would suggest reading this:

https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspiceiv-voltage-controlled-switches.html

As you selected a Vh to be 0V, the resistance of the switch will be 1Ohm when the control voltage is higher that 0.5V and 1MOhm when it is smaller than 0.5V, that is your threshold voltage (Vt). In your capture, the control voltage is constant, so the switch is not changing.